# Interpretation of "we don't anticipate any objection"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> We do not anticipate any objections to your proposal.

Does it simply mean "we forsee there won't be any objections to your proposal", or "we won't object your proposal"?

I'm asking because I'm looking at a translated version and it  suggests it means the latter.

Comment: It could mean either, depending on the context as the speaker perceives it. The former is the more likely choice, unless the politics makes it impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, as you suggested, it means "*we foresee there won't be any objections to your proposal*".

But in a certain context, like where the person or group saying this is the person or group who will make the decision, and the investigation stages are complete, then you might reasonably *infer* it to mean "*we won't object your proposal*". We sometimes use this roundabout language when we've made a decision, but not yet made it public or official.

Either way, it was irresponsible of the translator to translate the inferred meaning rather than the literal meaning.

Comment: I remember being told when applying to a school (by the person who makes the acceptance decisions) that they "see no reason they wouldn't accept me." And then I was rejected. So clearly not absolute in that sense (as in, this doesn't guarantee that some "unforeseen" objections won't come up later).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it simply means "We forsee (or anticipate) that there are unlikely to be any objections to your proposal".

"We won't object to your proposal." is an incorrect translation.